# What Japanese font is this used in the TeikouPenguin YT channel opening?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-design, web-fonts

what is [image: テイコウペンギン] font used in the opening of the テイコウペンギン youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/@teipen.official/videos
Ive tried using font recognizers but nothing...

Comment: Try using likefont.com - if you can't find it automatically, they have a forum where you can ask.